# Element not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem with an element not being found. I have this Ui-State from ui-router called `AuthDesc`, And for the `templateURL` I have this:

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/normalize.css" media="screen">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  </head>
  <body>

<textarea id="SimpleMDE">
# This one autosaves!
By default, it saves every 10 seconds, but this can be changed. When this textarea is included 
in a form, it will automatically forget the saved value when the form is submitted.
</textarea>

  </body>
```

And for the `Controller` I have this:

```
(function(angular) {
  var app = angular.module('ForumApp');

  app.controller('authDescCtrl', ["$scope", "$mdDialog", "$state", "$firebaseObject","refService","currentAuth",authDescCtrl])

  function authDescCtrl($scope, $mdDialog, $state, $firebaseObject,refService,currentAuth){

      $scope.topic = $firebaseObject(refService.ref().child("Topics"))


    $scope.goToPerson = function(person, event) {
      $mdDialog.show(
        $mdDialog.alert()
        .title('Navigating')
        .textContent('Inspect ' + person)
        .ariaLabel('Person inspect demo')
        .ok('Neat!')
        .targetEvent(event)
      );
    };

    $scope.goToTopic = function(avatar, date, email, title, uid, username, value) {
      $state.go("authHome.topic", {
        "AVATAR": avatar,
        "DATE": date,
        "EMAIL": email,
        "TITLE": title,
        "UID": uid,
        "USERNAME": username,
        "VALUE": value
      })

    }

  }

 new SimpleMDE({
            element: document.getElementById("SimpleMDE"),
            spellChecker: true,
            autosave: {
                enabled: true,
                unique_id: "SimpleMDE",
        },
    });

})(angular);
```

You can see in the last couple lines of controller that there is a new MDE Generator, however the console states that the element cannot be found:

> SimpleMDE: Error. No element was found.

I am confused. There is a `textarea` named `SimpleMDE`, but I do not know how is it not finding it. Here is a link to the code in the wild: https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/fourm2

I am afraid that the Javascript loads before the HTML, so it doesn't recognize the texarea with ID `SimpleMDE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your widget initialization in [`window.onload event handler`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)
For angular controller use:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        new SimpleMDE({
            element: document.getElementById("SimpleMDE"),
            spellChecker: true,
            autosave: {
                enabled: true,
                unique_id: "SimpleMDE",
        },
    });

});
```

Comment: And how do i do that? You know this is a controller right?

Comment: you can use $document.ready(function(){...}) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document

Comment: Or one from upadated answer )

Comment: Can you go back on cloud9?

Comment: Referencing an ID is not the Angular way, define a directive and use `$element` instead - it will be much quicker than `onload` aswell.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it also with this code :

```
$timeout(function() {

new SimpleMDE({
element: document.querySelector("#SimpleMDE"),
spellChecker: true,
autosave: {
enabled: true,
unique_id: "SimpleMDE",
}
});
});
```